# angular templateurl not found via webapack in production

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I have a angular 1.5 app component in typescript. I am using webpack as build tool. I have following component-

```
import {Component} from "../../common/decorators"

const app = angular.module('app');
 @Component(app, {
  selector: 'navComponent',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  styleUrls: './nav.style.scss',
  templateUrl: './nav.template.html'
 })
 class navComponent {
 static $inject = ['$scope', '$attrs', '$element'];

 constructor(private $element, $scope: ng.IScope, $attrs) { 

 }   
}
```

and the decorator is

```
export const Component = function(module: ng.IModule, options: {
  selector:string,
  controllerAs?: string,
  styleUrls?: string,
  template?: string,
  templateUrl?: string
}) {
  return (controller: Function) => {
   module.component(options.selector, angular.extend(options, {   controller: controller }));
 }
}
```

It works fine in local machine but after doing webpack build, it doesnt work in production with bundle.js

Here is the loader i am using.

```
loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader',
        }
```

Here is the error message:

Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /components/nav/nav.template.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to embed your template:

```
...
template: require('./nav.template.html')
...
```

If you want to use separate template file you may use `CopyWebpackPlugin`. But you will get one extra request for every file when you deploy your app.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works. I am wondering why the url didn't work? Besides, what is the best practice to deal with html file using webpack. separate call to a separate file or inside a module.

Comment: Url didn't work because of webpack dev server for example doesn't create the file in 'virtual' directory, so angular cant get it. About the best practice - can't answer... I prefer use `require` and webpack generates one big js file for my app. And it works without requests for any template html, only to get JSON from API

Answer (score 0):

since you are using es6 module import you can use below style of import statement to import your HTML

```
import mainTemplate from './mainpage.component.html';
```

then you can refer this template in your component as below

```
  export class mainPageComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
  public bindings: any;
  public controller: any;
  public template: string;
  public controllerAs: string;


  constructor() {
    this.bindings = {};
    this.template = mainTemplate,
    this.controllerAs = "vm";
    this.controller =mainPageController;
  }
}
```

now this loads your template but to handle it properly during webpack build process (used webpack 3 here) you can use [html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader)

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: { loader: "html-loader" }
  }
```

this should do you the trick